# We are using angular-agora-rtc web, how to check user is active in Agora server.?

Tags: javascript, agora.io

We are using sample from https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Angular-Agora-RTC The channel name is hard coded in the sample. When 2 users need to connect for a call. Ideally both should be on same channel. Is there a way for user-1 to check whether user-2 is online using agora-web-sdk?. If the user is online, how can user-1 share a channel-id with user-2?

One-to-one video call implementation using agoara sdk. For 2 user to have a call, they should be in same channel. Link above has the sample I am trying. Not sure how two user share same channel name with each other being in 2 different mediums at real-time.

https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Angular-Agora-RTC

If agoara provides an API to check if user-2 or user-1 is online after these user's have created clients in web. Is there a way to exchange "channel id" between active users.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such answer to this question anywhere on internet believe me i have searched for it, only thing that came to my mind is to use some type of User Base like Firebase, PHP MySQL etc to setup user and then login those users in your app.
After logging  in, set various flags for user presence like **is_online, last_active, is_broadcasting, is_audience** etc to determine which user is online.
You can then put channel name along with other user details when the user login and starts the Broadcast.
After the user is broadcasting, use those flags you used before and query them to get the broadcasting users and show them where ever you want for other users to join their broadcast.

This as simple as it can be in terms of explaining a really frustrating problem but in the end its only you who would have to implement any type of logic you can come up with.